# What is __methods__ and why is it calling __getattr__?

Tags: python, ipython, magic-methods

I have recently tried to implement a "pass through" on my a few classes to allow calling methods on specific properties of a classes using the `__getattr__` method.  This has broken (sort-of) autocompleting in ipython and I am curious to understand why.
First:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__():
        #create an instance of class ClassProperty
        self.class_property = ClassProperty()

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        #pass through calls to non-existent methods, print first
        print item
        return getattr(self.class_property,item)
```

When creating an instance of this class and then attempting to tab-complete in Ipython (0.12.1), it seems that several functions are called including `__methods__`, `trait_names` and `_getAttributeNames`.

```
In [1]: my_class = MyClass()
In [2]: my_class.not_in_my_class<tab>
__methods__
trait_names
_getAttributeNames
```

I am curious to understand what is happening.

Thanks,

P.S. I know that doing this is very opaque and is temporary.  Still, I'm curious.

**UPDATE**

Based on what I learned from the accepted answer below I have been able to successfully "pass through" autocompletion so that methods that exist in `ClassProperty` now autocomplete on instances of `MyClass`.  What was required to successfully pass through was an update to the `__dir__` method

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__():
        #create an instance of class ClassProperty
        self.class_property = ClassProperty()

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        #pass through calls to non-existent methods, print first
        print item
        return getattr(self.class_property,item)

    def __dir__(self):
        dir_list = self.__dict__.keys()
        try:
            dir_list.extend(dir(self.class_property))
        except:
            pass
        return dir_list
```

The reason why I have implemented this is because we are using python as an instrument control package with an ipython command line interface.  We have devices (i.e. a laser) that selects an actuator based on json config file.  We want to have top level access to the methods on the actuator for user convenience.

I would be curious if there are thoughts on my approach and if I am inviting any problems down the road.

Comment: I'm guessing it's some sort of `ipython` voodoo that you wouldn't see in the regular interpreter. . .

Comment: @mgilson in vanilla repl of course when you press tab you will get ... surprise surprise .. a tab character  ;)

Comment: @wim I mean that I don't think that `__methods__` is part of the python data model.  I'm guessing that `IPython` adds it to support things like tab completion, etc, so when you hit `tab`, `IPython` looks up the object and then looks in it's `__methods__` to find available completion matches.

Comment: IIRC, `__methods__` is some really old-school part of the type system that was removed in 2.2. [It's mentioned in the PEP for unifying types and classes from back in 2001.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0252/) It's gone now.

Comment: looks like the hit on `_getAttributeNames` is gone now -> https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/8081/files

Comment: [And so is the `trait_names` check.](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/commit/e1ced0b331f898664b33180b6a334869f8c87f37) That `dir2` function really doesn't do much any more.

Comment: Interesting, so if I understand this correctly, part of what is happening is that Ipython is looking at old methods/hooks that are no longer implemented, and so this code is getting these calls to properties/methods are no longer completed.  If I wanted to hijak the tab completion, I suppose that I could try to hook into these?  Could anyone point me to the ipython autocompletion code to browse around?

Comment: @Tony: [Here's the autocompleter code.](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/40c34d3369c3d271149e13ac07f1bd2f5a716635/IPython/core/completer.py#L356)

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IPython is asking your object for a list of its attributes, trying several protocols of varying levels of obscurity. None of these protocols are part of the core Python language (at least, not any more), and the current IPython source code seems to have removed most of these checks.

---

**`__methods__`** is a really old part of Python that was phased out when they [unified the type and class systems](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0252/) way back in 2.2, about 14 years ago.

It used to be the case that instances of built-in types would provide a `__methods__` attribute that would be a list of all the methods they supported. This required an instance of the type, and the system it was part of had a number of other flaws.

In contrast, user-defined classes provided the introspection system you're familiar with from modern Python, with object and class `__dict__`s. This was more powerful and more consistent than the other system, so when they unified types and classes, the class-based introspection system was kept and the other was removed.

`__methods__` is pretty much completely gone now. There might be some third-party legacy code still providing a `__methods__` attribute, but the only thing that comes with Python that still supports `__methods__` seems to be [this weird thing in idlelib](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/idlelib/rpc.py#l167). In Python 2, [`dir` still tries to look for it](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/object.c#l1882), though, and IPython's tab completion uses `dir`, so that's where the `__methods__` access is coming from. There should also be an attempt to access `__members__`, which you might not have noticed due to the message appearing on the same line you were typing on.

---

**`_getAttributeNames`** is a protocol apparently introduced by PyCrust, an alternative Python shell. If defined, a `_getAttributeNames` method would provide a list of all dynamic attributes an object supports through `__getattr__`. (This was before `__getattribute__` existed.)

[`_getAttributeNames` appears to have been introduced around 2001](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2001-August/100197.html), making it newer than `__methods__`, which disappeared around the same time frame. Some time since IPython 0.12.1, the [`_getAttributeNames` check has been removed from IPython](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/8081/files).

---

**`trait_names`** comes from [Enthought Traits](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/traits). For a class that uses traits, the [`trait_names` method](http://code.enthought.com/projects/files/ets_api/enthought.traits.has_traits.HasTraits.html#trait_names) is an instance method that returns a list of the names of its traits. It also accepts search criteria to list specific traits. Like `_getAttributeNames`, [this has been removed from IPython](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/commit/e1ced0b331f898664b33180b6a334869f8c87f37), apparently because the check isn't needed to handle traits (any more?).